# RegEx for matching prior versions to 1.11.14

Tags: regex, numbers, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

What regex expression would i use to verify if a version is less than `1.11.14`

Version like `1.9.15, 1.11.12` should fail and versions like `1.11.15` and above should pass.

I'm trying to do something like this `1\.(11$\.13$|14$|15$)` but clearly it's not going to work.

If there is a more efficient way as well I'm open to it.

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to use regex when mathematical value comparisons are involved.

Comment: What tool or language are you going to use for this?

Comment: I need to use regex. No other option is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said you have no other way than to use a regex, then you can use this regex, which will match any version smaller than `1.11.14`

```
^(?:0\.\d+\.\d+|1\.(?:\d|10)\.\d+|1\.11\.(?:\d|1[0-3]))$
```

**Explanation:**

- `^` - Start of string
- `(?:` - Alternation starts for various cases
- `0\.\d+\.\d+` - If first digit is zero then it matches regardless of whatever digits are present later.
- `|` - alternation
- `1\.(?:\d|10)\.\d+` - If first digit is `1` and second version digit is less than `11` then third digit can be any
- `|` - alternation
- `1\.11\.(?:\d|1[0-3])` - If first digit is `1` and second digit is `11` then third digit can only be one to 13
- `)$` - End of non-capture group and end of string

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/BYz477/1/)**

Comment: Thats exactly what i need! Thanks!